# NodeJs Debugging Client-Side Visual Studio Code with FuseJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have two application which has developed with Typescript. They are server-side and client-side application. I used NodeJs for them. On client-side also used fuseJs for hot-reload feature. But I have a problem I can't debug the client-side application. I'm always writing to console and there is so much "console.log() lines". 
I can debug my server-side. But I can't debug client-side. 
Here is my fusejs configuration:

```
const { FuseBox, WebIndexPlugin, CSSPlugin, CSSResourcePlugin } = require("fuse-box");
const { src } = require("fuse-box/sparky");
const fuse = FuseBox.init({
  tsConfig: "tsconfig.json",
  homeDir: "src",
  target: "browser@es6",
  output: "dist/$name.js",
  plugins: [
    WebIndexPlugin({template:'src/dashboard.html'}),
    CSSPlugin()],
});
fuse.dev({port:8080});
fuse
  .bundle("app")
  .instructions(" > main.ts")
  .hmr()
  .watch();
fuse.run();
```

I was run my client-side app like: node fuse.js but I read this docs: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html then I added "debugger" line to my code and I run it: node inspect fuse.js 
But I can't still debugging it. Somebody suggested chrome debug extension but I don't want change my any config or don't want to be reason for it. Is there any other way before try this extension? Can anybody help me?